# Calculate the best distribution for a group of numbers that can FIT on a specific number

Tags: math, google-sheets, numbers, spreadsheet

I have what I think is a interesting question, about google sheets and some Maths, here is the scenario:

4 numbers as follows:

> 64.20 | 107 | 535 | 1070

A reference number in which the previous numbers needs to fit leaving the minimum possible residue while setting the number of times each of them fitted in the reference number for example we could say the reference number is the following:

> 806.45

So here is the problem:

I'm calculating how many times those 4 numbers can fit in the reference number by starting from the higher to the lower number like this:

| 1070 | => `=IF(E12/((I15+J15)+IF(H17,K17,0)+IF(H19,K19,0)) > 0,ROUNDDOWN(E12/((I15+J15)+IF(H17,K17,0)+IF(H19,K19,0))),0)`

| 535 | => `=IF(H15>0,ROUNDDOWN((E12-K15-IF(H17,K17,0)-IF(H19,K19,0))/(I14+J14)),ROUNDDOWN(E12/((I14+J14)+IF(H17,K17,0)+IF(H19,K19,0))))`

| 107 | => `=IF(OR(H15>0,H14>0),ROUNDDOWN((E12-K15-K14-IF(H17,K17,0)-IF(H19,K19,0))/(I13+J13)),ROUNDDOWN((E12-IF(H17,K17,0)-IF(H19,K19,0))/(I13+J13)))`

| 64.20 | => `=IF(OR(H15>0,H14>0,H13>0),ROUNDDOWN((E12-K15-K14-K13-IF(H17,K17,0)-IF(H19,K19,0))/(I12+J12)),ROUNDDOWN((E12-IF(H17,K17,0)-IF(H19,K19,0))/(I12+J12)))`

As you can notice, I'm checking if the higher values has a concurrence, so I can substract the amount from the original number and calculate again how many times can fit the lower number in the result of that subtraction , you can also see that I'm including some checkboxes to the formula in order to add a fixed number to the main number.

This actually works, and as you can see in the example, the result is:

> | 1070 | -> Fits 0 times

> | 535 | -> Fits 1 time

> | 107 | -> Fits 2 times

> | 64.20 | -> Fits 0 times

> The residue of 806.45 in this example is: 57.45

---

But each number that needs to fit on the main number needs to take in consideration others; IF you solve this exercise manually, you could get something much better.. like this:

> | 1070 | -> Fits 0 times

> **| 535 | -> Fits 1 time**

> | 107 | -> Fits 0 times

> **| 64.20 | -> Fits 4 times**

> **The residue of 806.45 in this example is: 14.65**

When I’m talking about residue I mean the result when subtracting, I’m sorry if this is not clear, it’s hard to me to explain maths in English, since is not my native language, please see the spreadsheet and make a copy to better understand what I’m trying to do, or suggest me a way to explain it better if possible.

So what would you do to make it work more efficient and "smart" with the minimum possible residue after the calculation?

Here is the Google's spreadsheet for reference and practice, please make a copy so others can try their own solutions:

[LINK TO SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bnw85KgFyduwgML654lzuzuUU80o5D9qtQjJLqfGSoA/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

Comment: To begin, 1000 - (1*535) - (2*107) = 251, not 57.45. Similarly, I'm not sure how you arrived at your calculation that (1*535) + (4*64.20) = 1000-14.65 ... In fact, I calculate that there are five ways of reaching the closest number to 1000 using the given four numbers — e.g., (1*535) + (7*64.20) -or- (1*535) + (3*107) + (2*64.20) -or- (2*107) + (12*64.2) and two other possibilities —  and neither option you've suggested is one of those five viable combinations. Please check your math and then clarify the intended goal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but it looks like an integer programming problem -- minimize 1000 minus linear combination of given numbers (with nonnegative integer coefficients), subject to constraint that linear combination must be less than or equal to 1000. There are several packages for such problems; I've worked with GLPK and it seemed good. Maybe it's possible to solve such problems in a spreadsheet, but it seems like you would make faster progress by using a suitable package.

Comment: Take in consideration that I’m trying to find a way to automatically calculate the “times” a number fits in another but considering all other numbers (the four numbers I’ve mention before) if you see the formula I have used, I’m rounding to the lowest number the result for each, since I don’t want decimals in the result of times.

Comment: Analyzing this all again, while your post is using $1000 as the "get-closest-to" amount, it seems you are actually trying to get closest to your Euro amount of €806.45. Please edit your post to correct this misinformation. I just spent over an hour reworking and rerunning perfectly good formulas that came up with "wrong results"—only to finally discover that the information in the post itself is incorrect. Carefulness in posting avoids inefficiency and frustration for those who volunteer their time here.

Comment: @ErikTyler I’m truly sorry about this mistake, It really wasn’t intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all current formulas in H12:H15.

Then place this mega-formula in H12:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(E12,QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)&" "&I12&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)&" "&I13)&"|"&(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)*I12)+(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)*I13))),"|"),"Select Col1")&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I14),1,0)&" "&I14)&"|"&QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)&" "&I12&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)&" "&I13)&"|"&((SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)*I12)+(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)*I13)))),"|"),"Select Col2")+TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I14),1,0)*I14)),"|"),"Select Col1")&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I15),1,0)&" "&I15)&"|"&QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)&" "&I12&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)&" "&I13)&"|"&(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)*I12)+(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)*I13))),"|"),"Select Col1")&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I14),1,0)&" "&I14)&"|"&QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)&" "&I12&" / "&TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)&" "&I13)&"|"&((SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I12),1,0)*I12)+(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I13),1,0)*I13)))),"|"),"Select Col2")+TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I14),1,0)*I14)),"|"),"Select Col2")+TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(E12/I15),1,0)*I15)),"|"),"Select Col2, Col1 WHERE Col2 <= "&E12&" ORDER BY Col2 Asc, Col1 Desc"),2,TRUE)," / ",0,0))," "),"Select Col1"))`

Typically, I explain my formulas. In this case, I trust that readers will understand why I cannot explain it. I can only offer it in working order.

To ***briefly*** give the general idea, this formula figures out how many times each of the four numbers fits into the target number *alone* and then adds every possible combination of all of those. Those are then limited to only the combinations less than the target number and sorted smallest to largest in total. Then a `VLOOKUP` looks up the target number in that list, returns the closest match, `SPLIT`s the multiples from the amounts (which, in the end, have been concatenated into long strings), and returns only the multiples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik, that just worked amazingly, still, I have noticed something that could be better and maybe you can figure out how to do it...

Let's take another reference number for a new example: 2060.48... with your solution the distribution would go like this:

64.20 => 12 times 
107 => 12 times
Residue => 6.08

Which is great, but there is a better way distributing between all numbers, like this:

64.20 => 2 times
107 => 3 times
535 => 1 time
1070 => 1 time
Residue => 6.08

with your solution looks like the higer values are never used, please check the link below.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bnw85KgFyduwgML654lzuzuUU80o5D9qtQjJLqfGSoA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Given your post example data, there were three combinations that totaled your target. Given the example of 2060.48 Euros, there are 22 combinations of the four numbers that could arrive at the closest number (2054.40). So it isn't that the formula never chooses higher numbers; it just chooses the first match it finds. Again, however, with this being a free forum and my having a full schedule of paying clients, my time to give to forums is limited. I devoted 1.5 hours to this yesterday (where I normally expect to spend 3 - 5 minutes per post). So I'll let you and others take it from here.

Comment: I understand, don’t worry and I really thank you for your efforts, as we said in Costa Rica... Pura Vida!